# Can i use defer attribute in inline js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
    <!doctype html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" defer></script>
     <script defer> // Can I use defer atttribute here?
           //Inline js code 
    </script>
    </head>
    <body> 

    </body>
    </html>
```

Here can I use defer attribute to inline JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible. Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script):

> **defer**: This attribute must not be used if the src attribute is absent (i.e. for inline scripts), in this case it would have no effect.

For the functionality you want, you'll have to do one of the following:

- Put the script into a separate file and set a `src`
- Put the inline script at the end of the `<body>`
- Wrap the whole code of the script inside a DOMContentLoaded listener

Comment: you can also add the `type="module"` attribute to mimic the defer behaviour

Answer (score 2):

No

> The defer attribute is a boolean attribute.
>
> When present, it specifies that the script is executed when the page
>   has finished parsing. Note: The defer attribute is only for external
>   scripts (should only be used if the src attribute is present).

You can refer [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp) for more

Answer (score 1):

The `defer` attribute has no effect on inline code. An alternative is using the `type="module"` attribute, which will defer the code execution:

```html
<script type="module">
<!-- inline code-->
</script>
```